# How to use the External JAVA libraries with Test Engine hosted on Linux

Tags: web-api-testing, ready-api

We are using the Test Engine to run our Ready API test suites and this server is a Linux machine.

We are referring the java library (com.jcraft.jsch.*) within groovy script and this is used for file upload. this works fine while running the test in local with the Ready API application but while the same test with Test Engine, this suites fails as Test Engine is not able to find the the reference of java library(refere below error).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZaR0.png)

Can you help us with below questions

- Is there a default location which the Test Engine looks for external library reference?
- Is there a way to have our own custom path for external reference and let the Test Engine refer this path?

We looked into the official documentation, it has the details of path for Ready API but not for Test Engine